# Hide dynamically created HTML element with JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am creating a table row with a "spinner" to show actions when a button is pressed.

I append the row id to the spinner's id to be able to target it specifically.

For example row 21: **`#spinnerAction-21`**

While iterating through the data set, I add the name to array, so I can hide all of them after the html is inserted into the page.

Though I can't get my spinners to hide.I tried using inline CSS visibility to hidden but I couldn't un-hide it when I was done.

***Any help on hiding my spinners? Is there a better way to do this?***

```
var spinnerArray = $.makeArray();

for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
    html += '<tr>';
    html += '<td>';

    //other html output

    html += '<i class="fa fa-spinner fa-spin" id="spinnerAction-' + data[i].entry_id + '" style="font-size:24px;color:dodgerblue;"></i>';

    html += '</td>';//end button comlumn
    html += '</tr>';//end row

//Add a reference to the spinner for that row to hide.
    spinnerArray.push("#spinnerAction-" + data[i].entry_id);

}//end for

// insert the html rows
$('#display_info').append(html);

//hide the spinner in each row
$.each(spinnerArray, function (index, val) {
$(val).hide();
});
```

Comment: I'd strongly advise against using incrementally generated `id` attributes like this. It leads to needlessly complicated code which is difficult to read and maintain. Instead use common class names and select related elements by DOM traversal. I would give you a more concrete example of how to do this, but the structure of your page is unclear given the JS alone.

Comment: that's because `val` isn't the object it's the value of the spinner, it's not the element. You have to grab the spinner and use `.hide()`

Comment: @OrthoHomeDefense `spinnerArray` is a list of element IDs (with a preceding #).

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/gqxt7u0v/  You logic appears to be working as is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For anyone else running across this post, I ended up replacing

```
 spinnerArray.push("#spinnerAction-" + data[i].entry_id);
```

with

```
spinnerArray.push("spinnerAction-" + data[i].entry_id);
```

Removing the `#`

Then adding the `#` back in the

```
$.each(spinnerArray, function (index, val) {
                $('#' + val).hide();
            });
```

Comment: @OrthoHomeDefense gave me the idea when he said it was the id with the `#`, removing that from the name added to the array allowed the `hide()` line to be evaluated properly.